# Can non web application make valence call?

Tags: desire2learn, valence

We need a non-web C# application to create users and enrollments and like to schedule this to run daily using windows schedule job.

Questions: a. Can a non web application make valence call?
           b. if non web application is feasible, how to use the tokens stored in the session returning back from the shibboleth authentication?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can use any .NET library for making HTTP requests to make Valence calls from a non-web app. You will need to harvest the user credentials (the id and the key) by hand for non-interactive use by using one of the API test tools that are available (http://devs.valence.desire2learn.com/2014/10/28/the-api-test-tool-a-developers-secret-weapon/).